# XML file copy issues c# "XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource "

Tags: c#, xml, copy

In my program, I am checking to see if an xml file exists. If the file is not there, I simply create it in the specified directory, then attempt to copy the contents of another xml into the new xml file. Likewise if the file exists, I will copy the contents of another file and overwrite the existing file.  When I run my application and check the directory, the file that I want outside xml code copied too says "XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource".

So far I have tried : System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetPath); for the file copying.

my code block looks similar to this:

```
string sourceFile= "C:\\fileIWantToCopy.xml;
string targetpath= "C:\\NeedsFilledWithSourceContents.xml;

if (File.Exists(targetPath) == false) {
    File.Create(targetPath);
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetPath, true);
} else {
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetPath, true);
}

XDoc.Save(String.Format(targetPath));
```

Again I just need some tips on how I can copy the contents of one xml file to another fresh, newly created one without the "XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource" error. My top line of the source xml doc is :

< ? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ? >

then proceeds to have typical head/body construction.

Do I need to write content to the new file before I can copy anything over to it?

Thanks

Comment: The <? ... ?> is not an XML element. Each XML document must have exactly one root element. If you have <head>...</head><body>...</body>, then there are two top level elements, which is not valid.

Comment: What is XDoc exactly? you look like you try to save something into a file, but we don't know what it is, neither why you copy a file first...

Answer (score 3):

Either use `System.IO` file operations to copy an existing file OR save an `XDocument` that you have in memory. But doing both makes absolutely no sense!

```
if (File.Exists(sourceFile)) {
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetPath, true);
} else {
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XComment("This is a test"),
        new XElement("root")
    );
    doc.Save(targetPath);
}
```

---

If you want to save an `XDocument` this should be sufficient, no file needs to be created in advance.

```
doc.Save(targetPath);
```

The description on MSDN says

> ```
> XDocument.Save(String)
> ```
>
> Serialize this XDocument to a file, overwriting an existing file, if it exists.

All nodes must be embedded in a single root node (any name will do) and at least the root node must exist

OK

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<html>
    <head />
    <body />
</html>
```

WRONG (two root nodes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<head />
<body />
```

WRONG (no root node)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

---

Also, I do not see what the `String.Format` is good for, with no additional parameters.

And I also dislike the `if (File.Exists(targetPath) == false)`. Better: `if (!File.Exists(targetPath))`. Even better, reverse the condition in order to have a positive question

```
if (File.Exists(targetPath)) {
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetPath, true);
} else {
    File.Create(targetPath);
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetPath, true);
}
```